# Replace data type in dataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I wonder how to replace types in data frame. In this sample I want to replace all strings to 0 or NaN. Here is my simple df and I try too do:

```
df.replace(str, 0, inplace=True)
```

or

```
df.replace({str: 0}, inplace=True)
```

but above solutions does not work.

```
     0   1   2
0  NaN   1   'b'
1    2   3   'c'
2    4  'd'   5
3   10  20  30
```

Comment: Please share a sample of your dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this code will visit every cell in the data frame , and if it was nan or string will replace them with 0

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, np.nan],
                   'B': [np.nan, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                   'C': ['a', 10, 500, 'd', 'e']})
print("before >>> \n",df)

def replace_nan_and_strings(cell_value):
    if pd.isnull(cell_value) or isinstance(cell_value,str):
        return 0
    else :
        return cell_value

new_df=df.applymap(lambda (x):replace_nan_strings(x))

print("after >>> \n",new_df)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it is exacly what i need :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df = df.replace('[a-zA-Z]', 0, regex=True)
```

This is how I tested it:

```
'''
     0   1   2
0  NaN   1   'b'
1    2   3   'c'
2    4  'd'   5
3   10  20  30
'''

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard()

df = df.replace('[a-zA-Z]', 0, regex=True)


print(df)
```

Output:

```
      0   1   2
0   NaN   1   0
1   2.0   3   0
2   4.0   0   5
3  10.0  20  30
```

New scenario as requested in the comments below:

Input:

```
'''
     0   '1'   2
0  NaN   1   'b'
1    2   3   'c'
2    '4'  'd'   5
3   10  20  30
'''
```

Output:

```
     0 '1'   2
0  NaN   1   0
1    2   3   0
2  '4'   0   5
3   10  20  30
```

Comment: ok. Your solution is great, but what if digits are strings too and I want to replace only letters?

Comment: @yellowFlower: The solution will still work if the digits are string. That is, it will still only replace letters.You can try it out yourself. I just added that scenario as well to the answer.

Comment: sure ... no problem